# How do we compute the mole fraction of an ideal gas in a stream blended by mass flow controllers? For a non-ideal gas?

Tags: gas-laws

Consider a gas blending system consisting of two mass flow controllers, A and B, set to control flow to $f_\mathrm{A}$ and $f_\mathrm{B}$, respectively.  Consider that flow controller A is metering the pure gas of interest, which has an actual mole fraction of $x_\mathrm{A}$.  Flow controller B is metering a make-up gas which coincidently may contain trace amounts of gas A at a mole fraction of $x_\mathrm{B}$.

The mass flow controllers provide continuous estimates of $f_\mathrm{A}$ and $f_\mathrm{B}$; these are measured quantities.  Suppose also that we did some experiments and found the values of $x_\mathrm{A}$ (very close to unity or $\pu{1E6 ppm}$) and $x_\mathrm{B}$ (approaching zero, likely ones to tens of ppm).

To first order, the following equations provide reasonable estimates of the concentration of gas A in the blended stream at near atmospheric pressure, room temperature.  Experiments were carried out with $\ce{CO2}$ (gas A) in $\ce{N2}$ (gas B).  A $\ce{CO2}$ gas analyzer was used to estimate the mole fraction of gas A in the blend, $x_\mathrm{T}$.  We can compute the mass flow ratio of gas A by

$r = \dfrac{f_\mathrm{A}}{(f_\mathrm{A} + f_\mathrm{B})}$

or

$r = \dfrac{f_\mathrm{A}}{f_\mathrm{T}}$

where $f_\mathrm{T} = f_\mathrm{A} + f_\mathrm{B}$.  Further, we compute the mole fraction of gas A in the blend as

$x_\mathrm{T} = r \cdot \left(x_\mathrm{A} - x_\mathrm{B} \right) + x_\mathrm{B}$

My question again is: How do we compute the mole fraction of an ideal gas in a stream blended by mass flow controllers?

I'd like to do this in a rigorous manner, or correctly, possibly accounting for any non-ideal behavior of $\ce{CO2}$ in a $\ce{N2}$ make-up gas.

I came across [this reference](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ed077p1361) and believe the key to my problem is addressed therein.  The solution may involve the empirical rule of Lewis & Randall whereby the mole fraction of a component is equated to a ratio of fugacities of the component in a mixture to the pure component.  Certainly being able to compute the virial coefficients for the components may prove useful.  A key may also be converting a flow into a volume with an assumed time step.

Should I attempt to apply the some of the equations presented in the reference noted above?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be formatted using $\LaTeX$ syntax. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149) for details. This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  I can apply latex formatting; I wasn't aware this was supported.  This is not a homework question.  I will happily explore the solution further if deemed necessary.  Please provide feedback as to whether my most recent edits are okay, or whether I should add more content / show more work towards the solution.

Comment: What have you done in your analysis so far that says this applies only to ideal gases, and not to mixtures in general.

Comment: Can anyone make any suggestions as to further analysis?  I would be happy to add detail to the question.